# Send Push Notification to the server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM Push Notification in the server and in my android device .

Im able to send push notification from the server and receive it in my device.

Now im trying to send push notification from my device to the server.

Is it possible?

I heard about upstream messages but didnt found anything about it.
Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "push notification", as you just need make a call to the server?

Comment: I want to send gps coordinates back to the server . I thought about using simple post request or maybe using GCM . Thats why i said push

Comment: Push notification only applies from server -> client. What you need is a "background service" that sends the information you need without requiring to launch the app manually. Check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Thanks i thought about using a service with AsyncTask but how this will effect the battery if every 30 seconds i will send coordinates?

Comment: The service itself should not affect the battery consumption much (if you have coded it properly), the GPS power consumption will be the big drainer, but it's a must, given your requirements...